# How do I remove HTML elements with different values in VS Code using Find & Replace, while keeping its contents?

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code, replace

I'd like to remove all `<a></a>` elements (including classes, etc) in VS Code but keep the different values inside of the element. Is this possible using regular expression or another way?

**This:**

```
<td><a class="x">1</a></td>
<td><a class="y">2</a></td>
<td><a class="z">3</a></td>
```

**Becomes:**

```
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
```

Comment: If the format is always like that it is possible.. If html varies or can be nested it wont work.`<td><a [^>]+?>(.*?)</a></td>` https://regex101.com/r/usoX6Z/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help! Try the following in your find and replace tool for the find portion:

```
<a[^>]*>(.[^<]*)</a>
```

Then use the capture group for the replace portion:

```
$1
```

What this does is looks for `<a` then any number of characters that are not the closing angle bracket (`>`). Next it matches all characters up until the next opening angle bracket (`<`), then looks for the closing `</a>`. Finally, all the characters in the middle are what is used to replace the matched text, thanks to the capturing group `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Emmet:

- Select one `</a>`
- Select All: `Ctrl+Shift+L`
- `Arrow Left` (now you are just in front of all `</a>`)
- Execute command: **Emmet: Remove Tag**
- `Esc` to leave Multi Cursor

If there can be other tags inside the `<a></a>`

- Select one `</a>`
- Select All: `Ctrl+Shift+L`
- `Arrow Left` (now you are just in front of all `</a>`)
- Execute command: **Emmet: Balance (outward)**
- Cut: `Ctrl+X`
- Execute command: **Emmet: Balance (outward)** (select all `<a....></a>`)
- Paste: `Ctrl+V`
- `Esc` to leave Multi Cursor

If you only want to do this on particular `<a....></a>` tags don't use **Select All: `Ctrl+Shift+L`** but `Ctrl+D` and `Ctrl+K Ctrl+D`

If you need to do it a lot set some key bindings to the Emmet commands used